# How do I see the two nodes of most weighted egdes in R igraph?

Tags: r, networking, igraph, social-networking

I have an igraph network object constructed in R and generated weight information for each edge. I want to see the nodes of the most weighted edges (descending). What codes should I use to do that? Thank you!

```
# create an igraph project of user interaction network and check descriptives.

library(igraph)

#edge list
EL = read.csv("(file path omitted)user_interaction_structure.csv")
head(EL)

#node list: I do not have a node list

#construct an igraph oject
g <- graph_from_data_frame(EL, directed = TRUE, vertices = NULL)

#check the edge and node number of the network
gsize(g)
vcount(g)

#check nodes based on degree (descending)
deg <- igraph::degree(g)
dSorted <-sort.int(deg,decreasing=TRUE,index.return=FALSE)
dSorted

#check edges based on weight
E(g)

#the network will contain loop edges and multiple edges
#simplify multiple edges
g_simple <- graph.adjacency(get.adjacency(g),weighted=TRUE)

#check edge weight
E(g_simple)$weight

#igraph can generate a matrix
g_simple[]
```

Then I wanted to see who were interacting heavily with whom (the nodes of the edges with the largest weight)，so I tried

```
e_top_weights <- order(order(E(g_simple))$weight, decreasing=TRUE)
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the igraph function `strength()`, which gives the sum of the weights of the edges incident to each node. Here's an example:

```
library(igraph)

                                        # A small graph we can visualize
g <- make_ring(5)
                                        # Assign each edge an increasing weight, to make things
                                        # easy
edgeweights<- 1:ecount(g)
E(g)$weight <- edgeweights
                                        # The strength() function sums the weights of edges incident
                                        # to each node
strengths <- strength(g)
                                        # We can collect the top two strengths by sorting the
                                        # strengths vector, then asking for which elements of the
                                        # strengths vector are equal to or greater than the second
                                        # largest element.
toptwo <- which(strengths >= sort(strengths, decreasing = TRUE)[2])
## [1] 4 5
                                        # Assign nodes a color blue that is more saturated when nodes
                                        # have greater strength.
cr <- colorRamp(c(rgb(0,0,1,.1), rgb(0,0,1,1)), alpha = TRUE)
colors <- cr(strengths/max(strengths))
V(g)$color <- apply(colors, 1, function(row) rgb(row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], maxColorValue = 255))
                                        # Plot to confirm
plot(g, edge.width = edgeweights)
```

[image]

### Edit

Here are two different ways to find the two nodes (the "from" node and the "to" node) which are the ends of the edge with the maximum weight:

```
## 1
edge_df <- as_data_frame(g, "edges")
edge_df[which(edge_df$weight == max(edge_df$weight)), c("from", "to")]

## 2
max_weight_edge <- E(g)[which(E(g)$weight == max(E(g)$weight))]
ends(g, es = max_weight_edge)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But it looks like a degree data and it returns two nodes with the largest degree. I'm more looking at the two nodes of the the thickest edges. In my network, an edge is an interaction (reply), a node is a user. So I'm trying to find which two users have the most interactions among all. Is there a way to know this?

Comment: It sounds like you want the edge with the largest weight, then the two nodes that edge connects—is that right?

Comment: Yes! That's what I mean.

Comment: Perfect. Have a look at the new edits, at the bottom. Does one of those solutions work for you?